# How do I get req and res in a Sailsjs service?

Tags: sails.js

I've recently started using services in sailsjs to cut down on code in my controllers. Heres's an example of how I call a function in my service:

```
ValidationService.addError(req,res,'Password is too short.');
```

Notice I pass req and res to my service. Why arent these already available? How can I add them to the service so I dont always have to explicitly pass them?

As requested, here is the code in my service:

```
var errorCss = 'alert-danger';
var successCss = 'alert-success';

module.exports = {

init : function(req,res){

    req.session.flash = {};
    req.session.flash.alert = {};
    req.session.flash.alert.data = [];
    req.session.flash.alert.result = 'pass';

},

addError : function(req,res,error){
    req.session.flash.alert.data.push(error);
    req.session.flash.alert.css = errorCss;
    req.session.flash.alert.result = 'fail';
},

addSuccess: function(req,res,success){
    req.session.flash.alert.data.push(success);
    req.session.flash.alert.css = successCss;
},  

isValid : function(req,res){

    if ((req.session.flash.alert.result == 'pass')){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
},

clear : function(req,res){
    delete req.session.flash;
}

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code to know "why" you pass those to your service. At the very least is doesn't make sense why you need `res`. As that should be called at the bottom of your controller method.

Comment: I dont need res but I do need req because I am setting req variables in my service (req.session.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you read this already, but take another look at [the definition of the Sails services](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/587030dff01bfd26c7a400198c9757da61f1b2ef/reference/Services.md#what-are-services). This, basically, means that you can have in your services any common code, not necessarily something dealing with request and response. For example, there can be a part of your application that you are running from the command line: there will be no request or response in this case, but you still want to be able to use your services.

Bottom line, you are doing it right already by passing req/res. (Just don't overdo it: you should only create services for the code you are using in multiple places, doing it for every controller doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 0):

other refactoring is in order...

I suppose you could make some kind of global, but that would make the app go completely haywire. As users might now be sharing sessions. If it didn't just blow up altogether.

But looking at your question, I see you are using a service to validate password length. You should be using the model for this. Take a look at [Validations](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/Models/Validations.html)

In response to your comment....

Validations can be functions and can even depend on multiple fields too!

see below...

```
attributes: {
  website: {
    type: 'string',
    contains: function(cb) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        cb('http://');
      }, 1);
    }
  }

  startDate: {
    type: 'date',
    before: function() {
      return this.endDate;
    }
  },

  endDate: {
    type: 'date',
    after: function() {
      return this.startDate;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using the model to validate the data eventually but I first need to validate combinations of fields/values that dont map directly to an attribute.